# Desktop with dual boot (MacOS/Win10) with random crashes on both OS

Tags: multiple-monitors, multi-boot, hardware-failure, crash, desktop

not gonna waste your time so straight to the point:

First **what I mean by "crash"** - all monitors turn off as if the system slept, audio keeps going (yt videos keep playing) for a while between 3secs and 1 minute, Mouse and Kb are not responsive as far as I could figure since the monitors are off, the rest of the system shows no signals of restart/hang - lights and fans keep on going as nothing happened.

**Symptoms:** Random "crashes" not related to the amount of system load - happen in idle as well as while playing games or browsing. Began happening a week ago on a system that has been built 6 months ago and was fully stable up until now. No software/hardware changes made before the crashes began. They happen in Windows 10 environment as well as in MacOS. No Logs are being logged in the Windows 10 logger. Lots of warnings, errors and some critical but nothing logged before or at the time of the crash.

Eventually the Windows 10 becomes really unstable to a point of a total brick and inability to boot at all. MacOS seems to handle this better and its boot is not affected.

**What I've tried:** Reinstalled Windows 10 (because of the brick) - one day later the system have already went totally haywire - plan on reinstalling it again with the 1803 version after I'm done posting this. Changed the GPU since I thought it might have started dying. Removed both RAM sticks and tried each of them separately in every RAM slot of the MB. Disconnected 2 of the monitors and left only one (if that affects the GPU load and PSU has troubles keeping up). Ran memtest - everything seemed ok. Ran Unigine/tried to stress the GPU and the PSU - again no problems afloat. Temps in GPU-z for the GPU and in BIOS for the CPU seem ok as well.

Nothing mentioned above helped thus far. It seems interesting to me that the system seems stable for like half a day and then starts crashing and failing with an exponential rate but I may be imagining this.

**The system in question:**
MB  - AsRock ab350m pro4 /age: less than 1 year/
CPU - Ryzen 5 1600 with stock cooling /age: less than 1 year/
PSU - Seasonic S12II-620Bronze /620w, age: about or more than 5 years/
GPU - GTX650 TI Boost 2GB /age: unknown/, swapped with RX580 Nitro+ 8Gb /age: less than 1 year/
RAM - 2x Crucial DDR4-2400 CL17 8GB /age: less than 1 year/
SSD (SATA3) - Adata SU650 240Gb with Windows 10 /less than 1 year/
NVMe (M.2) - Samsung 960 Evo  240Gb with MacOS High Sierra /age: less than 1 year/
PCIe - Wi-fi/Bluetooth card I don't remember the manufacturer/model, I think it was some Apple compatible Broadcom /age: less than 1 year/
Monitors: 3x FullHD monitors (2xHDMI + 1xDVI)
Case: Zalman S9 NEO /if it is of any importance/

I've experimented with and tinkered lots of computer related stuff over the years but I've never had such mysterious of an issue and any help would be appreciated a lot.

Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.  This site is not well suited to this kind of question - too open ended, too uncertain what the issue is.  Please try on another site like a tech forum site which is more suited to back-and-forth discussion.